# Create a graph in Excel - y variable is binary?

Tags: excel, graph

I am trying to create a graph where:

X1   5  10  15  20

X2   10  20  25  30

Y    0     1     1    0

X1 is a minimum value of something, X2 the maximum, and Y the binary outcome--was my event true or not. In my head I picture it as a scatter plot where the horizontal axis is my min, the vertical my max, and there is a color coded dot that shows whether the event is true or not. I can't seem to create this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to do this directly in Excel. As a workaround, you could sort your data by column Y. Then make a scatter plot of the the data where Y=0. Then you manually add the data where Y=1 as a second "series", i.e. right click the chart and click on Select Data, then on Add (Excel 2007).